# Storing the index of a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, for-loop, indexing

I'm developing an android app with phonegap. I'm making an HTML table with some that with a `for` loop from localStorage. I need, for each row, to store the index i of the `for` to use it for retrieving an item from localStorage that has the name like the index. I have some code but the variable that i defined for that effect gets overwritten by the loop (of course). Here's the code:

```
<script language="javascript">
if(len != 0) {
var table = document.getElementById('hor-minimalist-b'); // get the table element
var tableBody = table.childNodes[1]; // get the table body
var tableHead = table.childNodes[0]; // get the table head
var thead = document.createElement('th');
var row2 = document.createElement('tr'); // create a new row
var headText = document.createTextNode('Dados');
  thead.scope = "col";
    thead.appendChild(headText);
    row2.appendChild(thead);
    tableHead.appendChild(row2);

for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {

    var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create a new row

    var cell = document.createElement('td'); // create a new cell
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var cellText = document.createTextNode(localStorage.getItem('key' + i));
    var xyz = "key" + i;    
    a.href = "alterar.html";
    a.onclick = function() { doLocalStorage(xyz) };
    a.appendChild(cellText);
    cell.appendChild(a); // append input to the new cell
    row.appendChild(cell); // append the new cell to the new row
    tableBody.appendChild(row); // append the row to table body
   }}
</script>
</table>
```

Maybe i'm not explaining myself too well. If you need any more info please ask. Thanks in advance. Eva

Comment: I am confused about your question... why do you need to store it? Where do you need to store it? Can you make it a global var, or an attribute of some element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put the key name in to a closure:

`function wrapper(i) {
    return function() {
        doLocalStorage("key" + i)
}}
a.onclick = wrapper(i);`

Comment: Where should I put this function? in the for?

Comment: Thank you! I put it in the for and worked right away! Many thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome. you can move the wrapper definition outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your question right, but if you want to bind usage of a variable asynchronously when doing for loop then you should wrap it in a closure:

```
    for(i = 1, c = arr.length; i < c; i++){
      (function(i){
        // i wont change inside this closure so bound events will retain i
        $('#id'+i).click(function(){
          alert(i); // Will alert the corresponding i
        })
      })(i);
    }
```